# Disable images in Selenium ChromeDriver

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Trying to disable images loading in ChromeDriver. I'm using the following code, however it's still loading the images. Any suggestions?

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
capabilities.SetCapability("chrome.switches", new string[1] { "disable-images" });
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\chromedriver\", capabilities);
```

Comment: I can't see "disable-images" in the list of Chrome command line switches. I do see mentions of "--disable-images" in a quick google search, but it doesn't seem to work. http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: Yep. There is mention of in a few locations. Did come across that site, but was unsure whether it was a comprehensive list.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I found the answer [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=20);

```
Map<String, Object> contentSettings = new HashMap<String, Object>();
contentSettings.put("images", 2);

Map<String, Object> preferences = new HashMap<String, Object>();
preferences.put("profile.default_content_settings", contentSettings);

DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
caps.setCapability("chrome.prefs", preferences);
```

Comment: How is this added to the chrome driver? What happens to the three variables it creates?