# ChromeDriver Ruby disable images

Tags: ruby, image, webdriver, watir, selenium-chromedriver

Is there a way to disable images in Chromedriver with ruby? There is a similar question but it deals with C# and I am not exactly sure how to port it over to ruby.

[Disable images in Selenium ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9433109/disable-images-in-selenium-chromedriver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it requires a hash to be sent to the "profile.default_content_settings" Chrome profile setting. I would try something like this:

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new
profile["profile.default_content_settings"] = { :images => '2' }

@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:chrome, :profile => profile)
```

Comment: Hi, bbbco. I have try this answer, but it didn't work. I am using `capybara (2.10.1)`  and

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who comes across this and is using chrome headless, here is how to disable images.

```
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(args: ['headless', '--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false'])
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:chrome, options: options)
```

Answer (score 0):

The flag to be set has changed since @bbbco added his answer. The correct flag is: `"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images"` making the working code:

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new
profile["profile.managed_default_content_settings.images"] = 2

@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:chrome, :profile => profile)
```

Answer (score 0):

Disabling notifications and images:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
  prefs = { "profile.managed_default_content_settings.notifications" => 2 }

  caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(chrome_options: { prefs: prefs })

  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new
  profile["profile.default_content_settings"] = { :images => '2' }

  options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(args: ['headless', '--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false'])

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
    app,
    browser: :chrome,
    desired_capabilities: caps,
    profile: profile,
    options: options
  )
end
```