# Python: Disable images in Selenium Google ChromeDriver

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler

I spend a lot of time searching about this.
At the end of the day I combined a number of answers and it works. I share my answer and I'll appreciate it if anyone edits it or provides us with an easier way to do this.

1- The answer in [Disable images in Selenium Google ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18657976/disable-images-in-selenium-google-chromedriver) works in Java. So we should do the same thing in Python:

```
opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opt.add_extension("Block-image_v1.1.crx")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opt)
```

2- But downloading "Block-image_v1.1.crx" is a little bit tricky, because there is no direct way to do that. For this purpose, instead of going to: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/block-image/pehaalcefcjfccdpbckoablngfkfgfgj

you can go to http://chrome-extension-downloader.com/
and paste the extension url there to be able to download the extension file.

3- Then you will be able to use the above mentioned code with the path to the extension file that you have downloaded.

Answer (score 134):

Here is another way to disable images:

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

I found it below:

http://nullege.com/codes/show/src@o@s@osintstalker-HEAD@fbstalker1.py/56/selenium.webdriver.ChromeOptions.add_experimental_option

Comment: This worked for a couple of pages, but not for say [this](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp) or [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_images.htm).

Answer (score 4):

**Java:**
With this Chrome nor Firefox would load images. The syntax is different but the strings on the parameters are the same.

```java
chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
HashMap<String, Object> images = new HashMap<String, Object>();
images.put("images", 2);
HashMap<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values", images);
chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
driver=new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);

firefoxOpt = new FirefoxOptions();
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("permissions.default.image", 2);
firefoxOpt.setProfile(profile);
```

Answer (score 3):

There is another way that comes probably to mind to everyone to access `chrome://settings` and then go through the settings with selenium I started this way just for didactic curiosity, but then I hit a forest of shadow-roots elements now when you encounter more than 3 shadow root element combined with dynamic content is clearly a way to obfuscate and make it impossible to automate, **although might sound at least theoretically possible this approach looks more like a dead end, I will leave this answer with the example code, just for purely learning purposes to advert the people tempted to go to the challenge.**.  Not only was hard to find just the content settings due to the shadowroots and dynamic change when you find the button is not clickable at this point.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()


def expand_shadow_element(element):
  shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)
  return shadow_root

driver.get("chrome://settings")
root1 = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('settings-ui')
shadow_root1 = expand_shadow_element(root1)

root2 = shadow_root1.find_element_by_css_selector('[page-name="Settings"]')
shadow_root2 = expand_shadow_element(root2)

root3 = shadow_root2.find_element_by_id('search')
shadow_root3 = expand_shadow_element(root3)

search_button = shadow_root3.find_element_by_id("searchTerm")
search_button.click()

text_area = shadow_root3.find_element_by_id('searchInput')
text_area.send_keys("content settings")

root0 = shadow_root1.find_element_by_id('main')
shadow_root0_s = expand_shadow_element(root0)


root1_p = shadow_root0_s.find_element_by_css_selector('settings-basic-page')
shadow_root1_p = expand_shadow_element(root1_p)


root1_s = shadow_root1_p.find_element_by_css_selector('settings-privacy-page')
shadow_root1_s = expand_shadow_element(root1_s)

content_settings_div = shadow_root1_s.find_element_by_css_selector('#site-settings-subpage-trigger')
content_settings = content_settings_div.find_element_by_css_selector("button")
content_settings.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally could not get the "profile.default_content_setting_values" flag to work, so what worked for me was this:

```
options = Options()
options.add_extension('Block-image.crx')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service("chromedriver.exe"), options=options)
```

To get the "Block-Image.crx" file:

Browser to "http://crxextractor.com/" (or other crx download tool)

And provide the URL:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/block-image/pehaalcefcjfccdpbckoablngfkfgfgj

The extension will download.

Rename crx file to "Block-Image.crx"