# How to reuse preloaded images with Selenium in Chrome driver?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

I am using the Selenium framework with Python, I am trying to save bandwidth while doing automation by reusing the images preloaded in the Chrome webdriver in my Python code. I am able to access the source url of the images, so far I am just re-donwloading them again with *requests*. I know for certain that normal browsers save images to temporary location on hard drive, and I guess Chrome webdriver does the same. How do I access these files with Selenium given that I know the src?

Answer (score 2):

You should reuse your chrome profile, something like that:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\path\\to\\your\\profile")  # Path to your chrome profile
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
```

About the path, this can be done by going to `chrome://version/` in your chrome, one of the settings there is your path, this will reuse your chrome profile, you might need to remove the last directory from the path if it's `Default` directory.

If you want your own profile that is not connected to your chrome, you can specify any path you want, and selenium will create it for you.

Comment: Thanks, I am able to locate images in profile/Default/Cache, however images are renamed with file extensions removed from file names. The new names don't correspond to the original names from the source file, or follow any kind of pattern. I also try to see if the creation date/time of the temporary files correspond to any pattern, not really.

Comment: Right chrome caches the images and rename them, that because if if page Y has an image `a.jpg`, and page X has an image `a.jpg` might be an issue, so chrome hashes the images name to prevent this. BTW if images aren't important at all, [disable them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28070315/python-disable-images-in-selenium-google-chromedriver)!

Comment: Is there anyway to control or disable this internal behavior of Chrome?