# Selenium taking too much time to load url

Tags: selenium, openurl

When i load the url in browser manually then it opens very fast but using selenium to open same url taking too much time to load. Can any one help me why this is happening?

```
driver=BrowserFactory.startBrowser("chrome", "www.abc.com");
LoginPage login=new LoginPage(driver);
login.username().sendKeys("xyzabc");
login.password().sendKeys("123456");
login.loginBtn().click();
```

Comment: which version driver you are using for chrome?

Comment: if the site loads tons of images or animations it will be loaded slower for a new profile. selenium creates a new fresh profile every time you create a webdriver. try with reusing the same chrome profile for speeding things. Refer to this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44668045/how-to-reuse-preloaded-images-with-selenium-in-chrome-driver