# How to disable video loading on Selenium with Chromedriver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am asking this question because there is a lot of stuff on how to disable videos autoplay, and images loading, but I could not find anything on video loading. Chromedriver is my only browser option. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Maybe you could use a chrome extension that does that. Then when you use selenium you can specify the relevant chrome profile that has this extension loaded.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28070315/python-disable-images-in-selenium-google-chromedriver  Check this one. It may help.

Comment: I can only find extensions to block autoplay, but not to disable video loading

Comment: Hi @GitJorgo, have you found the solution for this?

Comment: @LuisMiguel sorry for the late answer. In the end, I did not manage to find a way to solve this, I'm not sure it is even possible. Anyways, tell me if you discover how to do it :)