# How to remove CSS loading and Selenium text and make tests running faster?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How to make my Selenium script faster, guys. I have this Selenium script:

```
import time                                     
from selenium import webdriver                
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait                                       
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC                                
from selenium.webdriver.common.by 
import By from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
from xvfbwrapper import Xvfb                                                                                                                    
display = Xvfb()                                
display.start()                                                                                 
option = Options()                              
prefs = {'profile.default_content_setting_values': {'images': 2}}                                
option.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs) 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = option)      
driver.get("https://www.nike.com.br/chuteira-nike-premier-2-sala-unissex-153-169-171-309321")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.cc-allow'))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@for='tamanho__idM40F395']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button#anchor-acessar-unite-oauth2'))).click()
```

Guys, the problem is that this script is slow. How can I wait only for the time in this scenario instead of waiting longer than the time in this scenario to click on an element?  Because I think that because of this excerpt `wait = WebDriverWait (driver, 5)` the page expects more than it should to click on the elements, so I just wanted to wait for the time in this scenario, and also notice that in this script I took the load of images, I did  this to optimize the script, is it possible to remove the loading of images and text?  **I would like to remove some html and css text elements to load faster**. Can someone tell me how can I do this?

Comment: What are you trying to target with this selector `"//label[@for='tamanho__id40']"`? I looked at all the label elements on the page and none of them have a `for` attribute like that.

Comment: also, youve tagged both python-3.x and python-2.7 for your question. Which version are you using?

Comment: @C.Peck there are dozens of label elements with the `for` attribute attached to them on the page, but none of them have `tamanho__id40` as a value

Comment: @JD2775, yes that is more clearly what I saw too. (or anything even resembling `tamanho__id40` for that value)

Comment: @JD2775 I edited the question had put the URL and the wrong is right now :)

Comment: @C. Peck  I already edited

Comment: OK, thank you for posting your working code. However, I'm still not sure what you want to do. You say, "how can I wait only for the time in this scenario instead of waiting longer than the time in this scenario to click on an element?" What are you meaning by "*only the time in this scenario*"?

Comment: In particular, I know you are looking for " i would like to remove some html and css text elements to load faster", but I don't think there is a way to do this with selenium that would actually speed things up. So I'm trying to understand, big picture, what is your problem with your current code?

Comment: ^ what @C.Peck said.....also, `wait = WebDriverWait(driver,5)` does not mean it will wait 5 seconds until it clicks on the element.  I wanted to make sure you weren't confused by that as it appears you may be.  If the element is found in the DOM it will click it immediately.

Comment: I suppose you could try this if you really wanted to disable everything https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49031428/how-to-disable-css-in-python-selenium-using-chromeoptions

Comment: When I said in this scenario you mean necessary, I wrote it wrong, as to the purpose of the script, is that I really want to create a script in which I can add the shoes I want in the cart, but I want the script to be quick, I don't know how to use it  Selenium was the best option but this is why I wanted to make it quick @JD2775

Comment: @JD2775 The problem with this link is that it does not disable css, and I want to disable as much unnecessary stuff as possible

Answer (score 3):

I've made some research and below are my results. You have few options to try:

**1 Headless mode:**

It is believed that headless mode is faster. Check this answer [Running Selenium with Headless Chrome Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53657215/running-selenium-with-headless-chrome-webdriver) and here [Difference of Headless browsers for automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53083952/difference-of-headless-browsers-for-automation)
Your code would look like (loading pictures not disabled):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

import time
start_time = time.time()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True  # running in headless mode
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features")
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver')

driver.get("https://www.nike.com.br/chuteira-nike-premier-2-sala-unissex-153-169-171-309321")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.cc-allow'))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@for='tamanho__idM40F395']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button#anchor-acessar-unite-oauth2'))).click()
end_time = time.time()
print("Total execution time: {} seconds".format(end_time - start_time))
```

Total execution time (3 runs):

```
12.759594202041626 seconds
13.571481466293335 seconds
17.36514186859131 seconds
```

**2 Disable pictures**
Reference: [Python: Disable images in Selenium Google ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28070315/python-disable-images-in-selenium-google-chromedriver)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

import time
start_time = time.time()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

prefs = {'profile.default_content_setting_values': {'images': 2}}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)  # disable loading pictures
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features")
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver')

driver.get("https://www.nike.com.br/chuteira-nike-premier-2-sala-unissex-153-169-171-309321")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.cc-allow'))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@for='tamanho__idM40F395']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button#anchor-acessar-unite-oauth2'))).click()
end_time = time.time()
print("Total execution time: {} seconds".format(end_time - start_time))

Total execution time: 10.57245922088623 seconds
Total execution time: 13.770843982696533 seconds
Total execution time: 10.908315896987915 seconds
```

**3 Disable CSS**
Reference [How to disable CSS in Python selenium using ChromeOptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49031428/how-to-disable-css-in-python-selenium-using-chromeoptions) - Not sure this option is correct now because it does not improve waiting times and works only in headless mode:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

import time
start_time = time.time()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {'profile.default_content_setting_values': {'cookies': 2, 'images': 2, 'javascript': 2,
                            'plugins': 2, 'popups': 2, 'geolocation': 2,
                            'notifications': 2, 'auto_select_certificate': 2, 'fullscreen': 2,
                            'mouselock': 2, 'mixed_script': 2, 'media_stream': 2,
                            'media_stream_mic': 2, 'media_stream_camera': 2, 'protocol_handlers': 2,
                            'ppapi_broker': 2, 'automatic_downloads': 2, 'midi_sysex': 2,
                            'push_messaging': 2, 'ssl_cert_decisions': 2, 'metro_switch_to_desktop': 2,
                            'protected_media_identifier': 2, 'app_banner': 2, 'site_engagement': 2,
                            'durable_storage': 2}}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)  # disable loading pictures
options.headless = True  # running in headless mode
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features")
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver')

driver.get("https://www.nike.com.br/chuteira-nike-premier-2-sala-unissex-153-169-171-309321")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.cc-allow'))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@for='tamanho__idM40F395']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button#anchor-acessar-unite-oauth2'))).click()
end_time = time.time()
print("Total execution time: {} seconds".format(end_time - start_time))


Total execution time: 13.649555444717407 seconds
Total execution time: 12.698347806930542 seconds
Total execution time: 13.572114706039429 seconds
```

**Conclusion**

From what I see using `prefs = {'profile.default_content_setting_values': {'images': 2}}` is the optimal solution, at least for your case.
Headless mode does not add any improvements in speed.

However, results may be different depending on Selenium code and other factors.

Also, [here](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-decrease-the-time-taken-by-a-Selenium-web-driver-test-script-to-run-on-a-headless-browser-Firefox) you can find some good advices on how to make tests faster.
List:

- Use fast selectors
- Use fewer locators
- Create atomic tests
- Don't test the same functionality twice
- Use only explicit waits
- Use the chrome driver
- Use drivers for headless browsers
- Re-use the browser instance
- Run scripts in parallel
- Use HTTP parse libraries
- Pre-populate cookies do not load images in the web page

You are not using implicit waits, using css selectors which are faster.