# Python Is it possible to get request payload from a post request?

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests, screen-scraping, payload

I'm trying to webscrape the names and prices for this URL https://pricempire.com/search via the requests package. When I load the site there is a POST request called items and inside the request payload there is a attribute called captchaToken, basically I want to capture this attribute and use it to create requests for the other pages. I've been using Selenium to scrape the names and prices but it is very slow having to take 20 seconds to load each page. So my goal is to capture the captchaToken in the request payload which looks like this:

```
json_data = {
    'page': 1,
    'priceMin': 0,
    'orderBy': 'price_desc',
    'captchaToken': 'aaabbbcccxxxzzzyyy',
    'priceMax': 200000,
    'collections': [],
    'weaponIds': [],
    'wears': [],
    'priceProvider': 'buff163',
}
```

to speed up scraping of the site. But I don't know if its possible and from my research I don't know the answer to this question.

Comment: To make selenium run a bit faster you can add the option to not load images using [this commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28070315/python-disable-images-in-selenium-google-chromedriver)

Comment: Thanks, ill keep that in mind for my other projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In post request, you have to add data which is sent by the server as `payload` as json response and  `captcha Token` is also a part of payload data. Here is an example how to pull data (name, price) from api calls json response  as post method.

```
import requests
import json
URL = "https://public-api.pricempire.com/api/search/items"

body= {"page":1,"priceMin":0,"orderBy":"price_desc","captchaToken":"03AGdBq271Msp7k_yCTzgNsheZ1yRqLWykDZL17tIK9_YAVo2uZGc3cLH0sNhuZOFsnymBSAbuzRRo2w_Cy6kEEMxaRxgkuZUlXFcDzRPWgYs-Hy-fV5SpxLjU8rACYW3KwZ8y-js1Dye8weAdMfZSPeEBgQ9YP3zdbaPrUOJAHHmjkpqTxH7vPW-Cd2PXHtZf5NlgVkxCBUKIESAyMJ6FyKdNz_WxYdIJvK4uQa6nBdHxMlmQZx6rUgus65NxZkwTaY3BO36ju68WNerv-fQBqFdIz_6jUPfav41DYFiApv9O-MbdASQqpS-ma1TG76mQ82OQdzkqqvpZtAksBGa836HzsxfaOecgbZ2YbswAHr1dXxl919DbRnZum4Wr-UUZMQ66j8Iy5UA_g4B3Ir7IxTf50KhTOrNHtqIIYuBR4Vfz6scc5c7XqATeqMoMvL-06wbBWVATSI44","priceMax":200000,"collections":[],"weaponIds":[],"wears":[],"priceProvider":"buff163"}

headers={
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'User-Agent':'mozila/5.0/'
    }
jsonData=requests.post(URL,headers=headers,data=json.dumps(body)).json()


for item in jsonData['items']:
    name= item['name'].replace('★','').replace('|','').strip()
    price=item['price']['price']
    print(name)
    print(price)
```

**Output:**

```
Souvenir AWP  Dragon Lore (Minimal Wear)
100000000
Sticker  iBUYPOWER (Holo)  Katowice 2014    
49999900
Sticker  Titan (Holo)  Katowice 2014        
49999800
Souvenir AWP  Dragon Lore (Field-Tested)    
36388800
Sticker  Reason Gaming (Holo)  Katowice 2014
30000000
Souvenir AWP  Dragon Lore (Battle-Scarred)  
23618000
Sport Gloves  Pandora's Box (Factory New)
22000000
Sticker  Team LDLC.com (Holo)  Katowice 2014
16750000
StatTrak™ Ursus Knife  Crimson Web (Factory New)
15000000
StatTrak™ Talon Knife  Crimson Web (Factory New)
15000000
StatTrak™ Nomad Knife  Safari Mesh (Battle-Scarred)
15000000
Survival Knife  Crimson Web (Factory New)
14999999
StatTrak™ Stiletto Knife  Slaughter (Field-Tested)
14888800
Sport Gloves  Vice (Factory New)
13400000
Sticker  Vox Eminor (Holo)  Katowice 2014
13000000
Sticker  Team Dignitas (Holo)  Katowice 2014
11886000
StatTrak™ M9 Bayonet  Case Hardened (Factory New)
10999900
StatTrak™ Paracord Knife  Crimson Web (Factory New)
10000000
StatTrak™ Ursus Knife  Fade (Minimal Wear)
10000000
Sport Gloves  Slingshot (Factory New)
10000000
```