# Disable loading images in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm using [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) to automate user interaction on a development site. However, - the site is HUGE, so I copied everything except the images.

Now, when making the tests, it takes forever (2 min+) to load a page, since Cypress will wait for the images to render, before it starts doing it's thing.

Can I disable that somehow?

Comment: Use mode headless in your browser test, example Chromium: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/headless/README.md

Comment: Good suggestion. But ideally I would like to see what happens (just without the images).

Comment: You will see what is going on, because there will be video recorded ;)

Comment: check your browser settings, example chrome: https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: Link stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9433109/disable-images-in-selenium-chromedriver